# How to add custom toolbox

Tags: winforms, camera

Here toolbox in winform example on sdk of camera.
Here image information:
[Toolbox control in winform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Gm3Y.jpg)
I don't know create axLiveX1 add to winform.

Comment: Try to add more details to your question. Right now it is not quite clear - what are you asking.

Comment: I can't create control axLiveX1 add to windows form to show camera when connect to ip address.

Comment: It is still unclear and not very descriptive. Have a looks here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask